# How to access to Salesforce2Salesforce error messages?

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages, salesforce2salesforce

We have two instances (`A` and `B`) and we are pushing a record from `A` to `B`. There's a trigger executed on the instance `B` on insert doing various manipulation. When I look at the status in instance `A`, it is stuck at **Pending (sent)**. I have a good feeling that there's a problem with the trigger, but have no idea how I can see the error messages (normally, the user triggering the message is receiving the error by email).

How can I access *Salesforce-to-Salesforce* error messages triggered by `Connection User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question:

- Error are sent at the *connection owner email address*;
- Error messages are also stored in the **Connection History** section of the **Connection** tab in `B`.