# Salesforce 2 Salesforce programatic sharing, status "Invite"/"Pending (sent)"

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I'm trying to share an Opportunity from Org1 Sandbox to Org2 Sandbox. Connection is configured on both sides with auto-accept enabled, Opportunity StageName, Name, CloseDate the only fields published/subscribed to.

This works fine when done manually; "forward this opportunity" (status "Active (sent)"/PNRC.Status=Sent ), however it fails when sharing programatically (via a Trigger on Opportunity insert), status is "Pending (sent)"/PNRC.Status=Invite.

**EDIT: The Opportunity now appears in the target Org, but is not auto-accepted. When accepting it, the is no Account associated, this has to be done manually**

Things I've checked:

- No Invite emails to notify me of an incoming Opportunity share.
- There are no validation rules on the target org that would cause it to fail, as proven by the manual sharing working.
- No errors or useful information in the logs.
- Programatic sharing of a custom object works OK **EDIT: the manually shared Opportunity does not have a link to the parent Account**
- No error emails indicating a problem with the trigger or sharing (not sure if this should be expected)
- (edit) No error messages in the Connection History (as gleaned from [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14801/how-to-access-to-salesforce2salesforce-error-messages?rq=1))

Can anyone suggest a next step for diagnosing and resolving this problem? Let me know if you need any more information.